# Video full screen event communication between React Web and React Native Webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, addeventlistener, postmessage

hi im working communication between react and react-native

By the way... React detects the video(vimeo) full-screen event of iFrame, which is shown in React, but RN does not!

In other words, react detects events at full screen, but does not detect events when viewing the web through webview in RN.

this react code  eventisteners were put in useEffect

```
...
useEffect(()=>{
        if(window.ReactNativeWebView){
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('change') // is working
        }

        // I also put in document not working
        window.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', test, false)
        window.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', test, false)
        window.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', test, false)
        window.addEventListener('msfullscreenchange', test, false)


    },[])

  const test = () => {
        console.log("test change") // web working
        if(window.ReactNativeWebView){
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('change') // but this not working
        }
    }

return (
  ... 
                 <Vimeo
                    id={'video'}
                    onPlay={()=>test()} // on play video return message - is working
                    style={{
                        width : '100vw', height : '100vh'
                    }}
                    onError={onError}
                    video={id}
                    autoplay={true}
                    responsive
                    loop
                    showByline={false}
                    showTitle={false}
                    controls={hide}
                    color={'FF4C22'}

                    webkitallowfullscreen={true}
                    showPortrait={false}
                />
...
)
```

and rn webview code

```
  <WebView
         onMessage={(e) => onMessage(e)}
         mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={((Platform.OS !== 'android') || (Platform.Version >= 17)) ? false : undefined}
          bounces={false}
           onContentSizeChange={onContent}
           onLayout={onLayOut}
           javaScriptEnabled={true}
           scrollEnabled={false}
           allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures={true}
           allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
           allowsInlineMediaPlayback
           allowfullscreen
           mixedContentMode={'always'}
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          source={{uri : `${localTest}532522978`}} // localuri/>

const onMessage = (event : WebViewMessageEvent) => {
        console.log("d",event.nativeEvent.data)
    }
```

For testing, if you send a message from React, you receive the message from the RN webview message method. However, the message cannot be received through the function contained in the event lister. Can you tell me what went wrong?